# Inline CSS at build time using mustache/ruby

Tags: css, ruby, gruntjs, mustache, amp-html

I have project built using RUBY with grunt as its asset pipeline. At build time I need to take all the styles from the `/dist/all.min.css` file and place them into a custom style tag in the head `<style amp-custom>...</style`.

When developing I include the css as a linked stylesheet in the head. Which is fine. But when this is live the styles must be inlined.

I have tried a few grunt emailer tasks which are designed to take any linked asset and inline it, however this either didn't work or would take all linked assets and try and inline them and there are a few JS links that i do not what inlined, only the stylesheet.

**head during development**

```
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="/index.html" data-embed-ignore>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no,minimal-ui">

    <!-- Linked stylesheet for developing -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{{asset_base}}}/css/all.css" data-embed>

    <script async custom-element="amp-image-lightbox" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-image-lightbox-0.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js" async data-embed-ignore></script>
</head>
```

**desired head for production**

```
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="/index.html" data-embed-ignore>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no,minimal-ui">

    <!-- Inlined styles -->
    <style amp-custom>
      /* Custom styles here */
    </style>

    <script async custom-element="amp-image-lightbox" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-image-lightbox-0.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js" async data-embed-ignore></script>
</head>
```

I am using mustache for the templating engine and was think i could somehow include the css file if its available. This way when i do the production grunt task it could remove the linked style tag and generate the file thats included via mustache. But i am not entirely sure how to do that or even if it will work.

Comment: i think you have the right idea - if you get your compiled stylesheet to a file you can use ERB and html_safe to interpolate the css into the html. You can use `if Rails.env.production?` to distinguish between development and production logic.

Comment: HI max, thanks for the advice, Ill check those out now!

Comment: Sorry just relaised what you mentioned was from rails. This project is not using rails. is their a similar alternative for plain old Ruby of mustahce?